# Drawing clickable boxes in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am currently making a Chess game as a side project, but i'm struggling to figure out how to make the different tiles clickable. Searching only yielded a C# answer which didn't work.

I've used the creategraphics command to draw on my form, if that's of any help.

```
Sub DrawBoard()
Dim Board As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
Dim BlackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)

Board.Clear(Color.White)
For i = 0 To 3
    For j = 0 To 6 Step 2
        Board.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, j * 60, 120 * i, 60, 60)
    Next
    For j = 1 To 7 Step 2
        Board.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, j * 60, (120 * i) + 60, 60, 60)
    Next
Next
For i = 0 To 7
    For f = 0 To 7
        Board.DrawRectangle(BlackPen, i * 60, (f * 60), 60, 60)
    Next
Next
BlackPen.Dispose()
End Sub
```

This is the code I'm using to draw the chess board at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you post relevant portions of your code? What have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Maybe you should start with the easy part - the chess engine.

Comment: There was a c# post where one answer was a internal class. This doesn't work in vb apparently and the only other way I've tried is using countless if statements.

Comment: Drawing with `CreateGraphics` doesnt draw anything which persists; drawing rectangles creates a visual element, not an interactive control.  Perhaps a grid of alternating colored PictureBoxes?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to make the rectangles into interactive controls if possible.